# css image overlay slide-in from where mouse entered div

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-plugins, overlay, css-animations

I have a portfolio grid that I would like to have an overlay slide in on mouse hover, but I need the overlay to be able to slide in from all sides of the div as I want the overlay to a slide in from where the mouse entered the div.

Ex: if you enter the image box from the left side, then the overlay animation will slide from left to right, etc etc...

Below is a link of exactly what I need to do, but unfortunately, this website was made in wordpress.

[DNN Zone Website - Grid Portfolio Image Hover Overlay](http://demos.dnnzone.com/Portfolios/PortfolioGridwithStylishHoverEffect.aspx)

Any help finding a good css, jquery, or javascript plugin, or anything that you think might work will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
In Case anybody else land on the same issue, below is the link to the JQuery plugin.

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/